# UIRemoteNotificationType is UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone also if is all enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

in my app, i check if the user have enabled the Notification for my app, to enable the local notification, and i do it in this way:

```
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    if (types != UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)
    {
       //All enabled
    } else {
       //not enabled
    }
```

but i have a problem with some users that in the iOS setting have all enabled, they send a screenshot to me and it's all correct, but the code goes in the else statement, as if it's all disabled.
What is problem, anyone know how i can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: So what is the value of types in that case for those user ? Maybe they don't really enabled it fully. Is it full code you have there ? Do you register notifications ?

Comment: i can't know what value type is because they are in another country, and i can't connect it to my computer and run with xcode, they send me a screenshot of the setting, and it's all enabled in the native iOS setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
UIRemoteNotificationType allEnableType = UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge ;
UIRemoteNotificationType disableType = UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone ;
if (types == allEnableType) {
    // all enable
} else if (types == disableType) {
    // all disable
} else {
    // some enable
}
```

Another remote notification type is available after ios 5.0 `UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability`

Answer (score 0):

```
func isRegisteredForPushNotifications() -> Bool {
  if let notificationSettings = application.currentUserNotificationSettings() {
    return notificationSettings.types != UIUserNotificationType.None
  }
  return false
}
```

I used this in Swift 2, tested on iOS9.

Comment: and in Swift 3? I am unable to find .none :(